# Auto Populate Email Subject from Woocommerce Product

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

Amateur with programming (and love it), long time reader and first time poster.

I have set up a Woocommerce cart here at http://centrowireless.com/inventory/. I have a Contact for Price button made with the WP Call for Price plugin. I have made some customizations by changing the text to "Contact for Price", adding a div for some CSS and adding a mailto when the button is clicked:

```
public function empty_price($price) { return '<div class="contactproduct"><a href="mailto:offers@centrowireless.com">Contact for Price</a></div>'; }
```

My question is, how can I auto populate the subject of that email so that the subject is the specific product the clicked button is a part of?

Thank you,

Evan

Comment: Are you using a contact for price plugin? Sounds like you will need to add a filter to change the subject - let me know how you added the buttons and I can help with this. I think @Michael misinterpreted how the "contact for price" buttons were added to the page.

Comment: Yes. @madebydavid that is exactly what I used. I activated the plugin and then went in to the php to change the text it displays. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: which plugin are you using? Can you post a link to it? I think there is more than one which does this so I want my answer to be for the one which you are using.

Comment: @madebydavid I am using WooCommerce Call for Price Plugin by Algoritmika. http://www.algoritmika.com/shop/wordpress-woocommerce-call-for-price-plugin/

Comment: Are you using the pro version?

Comment: @madebydavid I am not.

Comment: Are you sure you are using that plugin? Did you change the theme at all for this? I'm asking because when I use that plugin - it just displays the text "Call for Price" next to the products when no price is set - it doesn't display a button like yours or enable the mailto stuff.

Comment: @madebydavid Yes I made some PHP customizations. I wrapped the actual button it creates in a div class that uses CSS to style the button. I then changed the text it outputs to "Contact for Price." --------------------------------------------------------

public function empty_price($price) {
   return '<div class="contactproduct"><a href="mailto:offers@centrowireless.com">Contact for Price</a></div>';
  }  --THANKS!

Comment: @madebydavid I plan on purchasing the paid version. Will that make a difference?

Comment: I don't think you need the paid version - I will write some code and add an answer. Maybe you could put your code in the question\?

Comment: @madebydavid that would be greatly appreciated. Have added the code and edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working for me, please give it a try:

```
public function empty_price($price) {
    global $post;
    return '<div class="contactproduct"><a href="mailto:offers@centrowireless.com?subject='.urlencode($post->post_title).'">Contact for Price</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: This works very well! Thank you! I don't have enough rep yet to Vote Up but hopefully a nice passer-by can rep you for me.

One question. When it generates the subject, I notice + marks in the subject, any way to remove these?

Comment: The `+` signs are the URL encoded version of a space - they will appear in the URL (shown when you hover your mouse over the button) but will not appear in the subject of the email - as shown in this image I made: http://i.imgur.com/eohebXq.png

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine that simply

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

would work just fine. Here's an example:

```
<a href="mailto:my@email.com?subject=<?php the_title(); ?>">Contact for Price</a>
```

Comment: I apologize. I realized that you want this in your archive page. Perhaps then
'<?php global $product; ?>
<a href="mailto:my@email.com?subject=<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ); ?>">Contact for Price</a>'

Comment: When I do that it just returns <?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_title() ); ?> as the subject

Comment: Any other ideas @michael?